# How to post ajax call with multipart/form-data?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, extjs, apache-commons

I need to upload a file from extjs page, via AJAX call, to the server. I am able to do it with simple HTML page to servlet but using extjs (v4.0.7) i am not getting file in my servlet when i pars request. Servlet recognizes multipart page but nothing comes with the call. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in my code?

EXTJS code:

```
var fileName = Ext.getCmp("fileName").getValue();

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'UploadServlet',
    method: 'POST',  
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
    params :{
       'fileName': fileName.trim()
    },

    success: function ( result, request ) {
        resultData = result.responseText;
    },
    failure: function ( result, request ) {
        resultData = result.responseText;
    }   
});
```

Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {  

    .......

     // Check that we have a file upload request
      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
          // display no file attached error
         return;
      }

      // Create a factory for disk-based file items
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File(tempDir));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );


      try{ 
          // Parse the request to get file items.

      ////// fileItems is empty, 
              ////nothing is comming from extjs page/////////
          List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

          // Process the uploaded file items
          Iterator<FileItem> i = fileItems.iterator();

          while ( i.hasNext () ) {                
             FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();

             if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
                // Get the uploaded file parameters
                String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
                String fileName = fi.getName();
                String contentType = fi.getContentType();
                boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
                long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

                // check if file exists
                File propFile = new File(tempDir, fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
                if (!propFile.exists()) {  
                    // Write the file
                    if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
                       file = new File(tempDir + 
                       fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                    }else{
                       file = new File(  tempDir + 
                       fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                    }   
                    //InputStream uploadedStream = fi.getInputStream();
                    fi.write( file ) ;
                    out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "  is in " + filePath + "<br>");
                } 

                ..... 
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't upload a file with AJAX.

Ext's `Ajax` can emulate it though. See the [doc of the `request`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-method-request) method. You have to use the `form` and `isUpload` options.

However, since you have to use a form anyway, you should look at [`Ext.form.field.Field`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File) (and, as suggested in the doc, to [`Ext.form.Basic.hasUpload`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#); that will give you a better understanding of the file upload problematic).

**EDIT:** In fact, [HTML5 and XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) adds support for file upload. Doesn't change how you have to handle it in Ext, though.